# Excell: how to link sheet to a cell?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am trying to see if there is any method to link a sheet to an excel cell. For example:
If I have a main sheet with types of fruit, I want to click the apples cell and I want that to take me to a sheet where I previously listed all my apple types and other info such as stock etc.
If I use hyperlink it open a new instance of excel. 
I just want to double click the cell and for excel to open the sheet that has all the info about that cell. The sheet should be hidden till then.

Is this possible? If so, how do you achieve it?

Update question: If I hide the sheet that the button is supposed to take me to, it won't open. I want to have only 1 sheet open and only when I click the button to take me to the sheet. In the mean time I don't want them open. I need this as I will be having hundred of entries and can't have all the sheets open

Thank you!

Kind regards,

Paul.

Comment: Update question: If I hide the sheet that the button is supposed to take me to, it won't open. I want to have only 1 sheet open and only when I click the button to take me to the sheet. In the mean time I don't want them open. I need this as I will be having hundred of entries and can't have all the sheets open

Comment: You've asked 5 questions so far, and haven't marked an "accepted" answer on any of them. You should consider doing so, especially if answers have resolved (or helped you to resolve) your problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a button<sup>†</sup> in the cell. Assign a macro `Button_Apple_Click` to it:

```
Sub Button_Apple_Click()

    Worksheets("Apple_Sheet").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Apple_Sheet").Activate

End Sub
```

Now clicking<sup>‡</sup> on the button will activate the worksheet "Apple_Sheet". Note that pressing a different button will not hide back this sheet—that would require a bit more coding. But, if you don't save the file, the displayed sheets will come back hidden the next time you open the workbook.

<sup>†</sup>*To insert a button go to the "Developer" ribbon and click on "Insert" in the "Controls" tab, then select the button from "Form controls". You'll be asked which macro should be run when you click on the button. Type the name of the macro e.g. `Button_Apple_Click`), then click on the "New" button. Edit the macro, then press [CTRL]+[S] to save.*

<sup>‡</sup>*Please note that this requires a single click. Your request of a double click in a cell in order to activate the worksheet seemed to me unnecessary; however—if you **really** want that—you might want to look at the `BeforeDoubleClick` event of the host worksheet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196564.aspx*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked great. Initially tried using a Pivot Table and that's why I had the double click in mind but that was too complicated for what I needed. Have a cool day!

Comment: Update question: If I hide the sheet that the button is supposed to take me to, it won't open. I want to have only 1 sheet open and only when I click the button to take me to the sheet. In the mean time I don't want them open. I need this as I will be having hundred of entries and can't have all the sheets open

Comment: @PaulBajan Also, unrelated to the question: you don't seem to mark your questions as "answered." May I ask why?